# Recommended way to install kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I was looking into the different ways of installing Kubernetes in https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/pick-right-solution/ but I'm still not sure which one is the best for me.

I have access to a testbed that can provision CENTOS 7.3 VM's through vagrant. This tesbed is basically a bare-metal environment in which the VM's are started up.

I can configure each host individually so I suppose kubeadm (https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/) would be a good way to go?

Comment: This is probably question more for https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Brandon, You can use Kubeadm, but the question is a bit broad IMHO.

Comment: It's a bit broad because I didn't provide enough info or because there are many ways of installing Kubernetes?. For the former, I can extend whatever information you need. For the latter, that's precisely the problem. I can't figure out which one I need from the many options.

Answer (score 0):

Brandon,

While the Kubernetes community supports multiple cluster deployment solutions simultaneously (mainly because there is no single *best* solution that will satisfy all the needs of everyone), Kubeadm (https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/) - is the right solution that we may suggest for you.

Kubeadm is a community-driven, cross-distribution cluster deployment and LCM tool, that is widely recognized as a standard way to deploy Kubernetes clusters with a wide variety of options.

Also, feel free to check the article (https://medium.com/@lizrice/kubernetes-in-vagrant-with-kubeadm-21979ded6c63) that describes the way of Kubernetes cluster deployment with Kubeadm and Vagrant.